# How to automatically execute a method after deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I've got a class `Foo`, it's `Serializable`. It represents a graphical object, and I want it to restore its handles to the state before serializing. All data is stored within the object, I just need a method to be called in the right moment. How can I achieve it? Is this possible in Java?

(I have my `Foo`s in a `List` in `Bar` object, and in some other places - that's why I don't want to do it manually.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures:

```
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

Implement this method, and call `in.defaultReadObject()`, and then do whatever custom logic you want.

Check the docs of [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for more details

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Wish things like this were taught in books more.

Comment: this only works for java serializer, twitter kryo won't use this