# Spring: Serialization of session scoped bean

Tags: spring, serialization

I have a Spring bean with scope session. This bean holds a reference to another singleton bean which is not serializable. What is the best approach if I want to serialize the session scoped bean?

The same question is already asked here: [Spring session-scoped beans (controllers) and references to services, in terms of serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o)

The accepted answer is that:

> [...]this issue is resolved in spring 3.0 by providing a proxy of non-serializable beans, which obtains an instance from the current application context

As far as I understand the speaker in the linked video it should "just work". But in my case it doesn't! When I try to serialize my session scoped bean i get a `NotSerializableException`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may mark singleton reference field as `transient`. Then check [How to execute method after deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343277/how-to-automatically-execute-a-method-after-deserialization) and load reference from `ApplicationContext`. 
Also, please provide stacktrace.

P.S.

It is not too good idea to use session passivation.

Comment: It is just slow and use a lot of IO. Currently we have a lot of RAM - it is enough to hold sessions.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But instead of implementing `readObject` in all my session scoped beans I prefer this approach: http://justonjava.blogspot.hk/2011/02/session-passivation-and-spring-part-1.html

Comment: The application runs on a Weblogic cluster with session replication enabled. That is the reason I have to serialize the session objects.

Comment: How are you getting your Application Context instance after deserialization?

Comment: No, your linked question DO NOT contain the example how to load reference from ApplicationContext. AFAIK it can't be possible because in order to get the ApplicationContext, you need to have ServletContext which you obviously NOT have in readObject method.